# check for duplicates when saving an appointment

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to prevent a user from double booking a therapist in the same timeslot that is already booked.

Scenario:
I have Amanda and Lisa. They both want to book Lorraine(Therapist) in the hour of 9am till 10am. Amanda Books Lorraine first at 9am to 10am. Lisa comes second and requests Lorraine from 9:30am till 10:30am on the same date as Amanda.

Now how do I prevent that from happening since Lorraine is already booked in that hour. I am currently using dateTimePicker for my time

Comment: how about actually programming something and post some code?. Please post code of what you ve tried and what you want to accomplish

Comment: dbCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Time, Date From Appointments WHERE TherapistName ='" + cmbEmpName.Text + "'", dbConn);
                dbConn.Open();
                dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand);

                dt = new DataSet();
                dbAdapter.Fill(dt, "Appointments");
                DataTable dtExists = dt.Tables["Appointments"];

                dbConn.Close();

Comment: please edit your code and paste your code, and format as such

Comment: bool founded = false;
                if (dtExists.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dtExists.Rows)
                    {
                        if (time == row["Time"].ToString() && (monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString()) == row["Date"].ToString())
                        {
                            //show cannot choose diffrerent;
                            founded = true;
                            MessageBox.Show("The Therapist is Already Booked for the chosen timeslot. \nPlease Change the Timeslot or Date"):

Comment: I will re-post the question with the code in the right format because i cant on the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have a collection of `Booking` objects that have properties `Start` and `End` you can detect intersections in this way:

```
public class Booking
{
    public DateTime AppointmentStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppointmentEnd { get; set; }

    public bool IntersectsWith(Booking otherAppointment)
    {
        // between
        bool case1 = this.AppointmentStart >= otherAppointment.AppointmentStart && this.AppointmentEnd <= otherAppointment.AppointmentEnd;
        if (case1) return true;
        // befor-eafter-start
        bool case2 = this.AppointmentStart <= otherAppointment.AppointmentStart && this.AppointmentEnd >= otherAppointment.AppointmentStart;
        if (case2) return true;
        // before-after-end
        bool case3 = this.AppointmentStart >= otherAppointment.AppointmentStart && this.AppointmentEnd >= otherAppointment.AppointmentEnd;
        return case3;
    }
}
```

Now you can use LINQ to check if there is already a booking:

```
bool alreadyBooked = bookings.Any(booking.IntersectsWith);
```

Comment: bool alreadyBooked = bookings.Any(booking.IntersectsWith);              What does the "Any" stands for?

Comment: Thank You I figured it out.